# Android setText error

Tags: android, styles, textview, settext

I have a view in the XML

```
<TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />
```

whose styles are defined in values/styles.xml as follows

```
<style name="TitleBarText">
        <item name="android:id">@+id/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    </style>
```

When i try to set the text from onCreate of the activity like this i am getting an error

```
TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
titleText.setText(getString(R.string.title_home));
```

In Eclipse i am getting this error

> title_text cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: try this..
<TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" 
          android:id="@+id/title_text" />                             and remove android:id="@+id/title_text" from style.

Comment: @Himanshu whats the change ? its the same right ?

Comment: first one was by mistake i have edited it now....

Comment: why cant we assign id in the styles ?

Comment: Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled, this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class) and you will use it very often.(In simple word id is view's property not styles's property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set id of the String resource in textview 
You have to write like

```
titleText.setText(getString(R.string.title_home));
```

**EDIT**

You have to set id of textview in `<Textview>` tag instead of writing in style of textview

Comment: i am getting an error in assigning the text view,, and yeah ur right about the getString().. had changed it.. forgot to make changes here